# adding an image from database and displaying it in html using php

Tags: php

How do I add an image from my database into php. I have created an image column in the database and added the images file path. I know it is something to do with the img src, but I just don't know how to write it correctly. I am not sure how to get the image to display.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $attraction_name = $row['attraction_name'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $long = $row['long'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];
    $image = img src =$row['image'];

    $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.$lat.' '.$long.' '.$cost.' '.$image.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just to place the `img` tag in qoutes:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $attraction_name = $row['attraction_name'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $long = $row['long'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];
    $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}' height='42' width='42'>";

    $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.$lat.' '.$long.' '.$cost.' '.$image.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, for some reason the images aren't displaying, but must be the file path that is wrong or something. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML 101

```
<image src="$row['image']" alt="image description" height="42" width="42" />
```

OR

```
$image = "<img src=" .$row['image']. " />";
```

Comment: This just shows an image that doesn't work in html at all times, and when I search and the results are displayed the file path just shows up - not the image

Comment: Is there any reason why the path for my images isn't right. I have checked all the folders and it seems to be right

Comment: What does you path look like @s_smi123?

Comment: img/database/country/img.jpg. So for example if I am trying to search for hong kong the images for hongkong would be in the hongkong folder

Comment: You're just going to have to double-check your paths. Since we cannot see them there is not way for us to test @s_smi123

Comment: Is there anyway to check what folder your database is in? I am using phpMyAdmin. I have the image folder in a bootstrap folder, and in the bootstrap folder is where I have all my php scripts, just don't know where the database is situated within the folder structure so don't know if the path that I have is right

Comment: The path to the database is irrelevant. The path from the page you wish to display the image on to the image is what is important.